# elliptic and parabolic theories for unbounded domain in R^n

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I'm self-reading Evan's PDE book. It discusses elliptic and parabolic theories under the condition that the domain $U$ is open and bounded, and the functions vanishes on $\partial U.$ I'm wondering if the can be considered in the whole space $\mathbb{R}^n$? It seems like that as long as the boundary term can be discarded then thing works, but I don't know what is the setting for this to let everything make sense. And do we still have any regularity property for the solution if the domain is changed to $\mathbb{R}^n$? Thanks for any help.

Comment: where is it needed that $U$ is bounded ?

Comment: It only seems to me that if we have $U$ bounded, then $\partial U$ can be stated clearly. And with the assumption that our functions vanish on the boundary, we can discard the boundary terms when doing integration by parts. In Evans, it used the space $H^1_0.$